# how to email php post variables

Tags: php, email

using this code i'm getting the output on confirmation page. I just want to send this as email and page should say thanks.

Code:

```
<?php
        foreach( $response as $key => $value) {
            if($key == 'paymentStatus') continue;
?>          
        <tr>
            <td class="fieldName" width="50%"><?php echo $key; ?></td>
            <td class="fieldName" align="left" width="50%"><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>


<?php
        }
?>
```

How to form a php mailer using above $key and $value variables?

Any help is much appreciated.
I tried :

```
<?php
$to      = 'ranjan08@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Transaction Details';
        $msg="";
        $msg.='<table><tr>';
        $msg.='<td class="fieldName" width="50%">'.$key. '</td>';
        $msg.='<td class="fieldName" width="50%">'.$value. '</td>';
        $msg.='</tr></table>';
$message = $_POST;
$headers = 'From: ranjan08@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ranjan08@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

And nothing is being emailed.

Answer (score 1):

At first, the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function expects $message to be a string, but you provide an array:

```
$message = $_POST;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You can use

```
$message = var_export($_POST,true);
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

To send the raw data or

```
$message = "";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $message .= "{$key} : {$value}\n";
}
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

to send a formatted email body.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Code above worked with the following lines: Amount : 9500.00
PaymentID : 76146065
SecureHash : 31F8C75429C1B54ABF46A491916B57EC51C5ACFF02216246CDBFEF9AE3472C7025EC41498AB68D88EE30A5654344A5E6B42CA4E116702C60D043E3669E71D3FD
Status : SUCCESS

Comment: But actual $response has more values e.g. Amount 9500.00
BillingAddress Test Address
BillingCity New Delhi
BillingCountry IND
BillingEmail ranjan08@gmail.com
BillingName Ranjan Kumar Singh
BillingPhone 
BillingPostalCode 400069
BillingState New Delhi
DateCreated 2017-05-26 17:14:39
DeliveryState New Delhi
IsFlagged NO
MerchantRefNo 1495799057
Mode LIVE
PaymentID 76146065
PaymentMethod 1355
RequestID 36711340
TransactionID 214505776

Comment: $response is a complete different variable than  $_POST, please make clear whats your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the variables? 
If the variables are set in the same file, then you just need to change the PHP `mail()` function: as per your script, `mail()` is set to send the value of `$_POST` variable, that might not being used considering that there is probably no form submission (no HTML POST method but GET one). So it may throw some error on call. 
Then you also prepared the `$msg` variable and your not using it.

I suggest you to try with `mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);`.
Also check the log files of your Apache2/NGINX, you will probably see there what you are mistaking.